# Visual studio 2022 console closes after running/ debugging code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I feel really dumb for having to ask this question, but how do I stop the console on visual studio 2022 from closing automatically after I run a code? When I try to run/ debug, the console opens for a brief moment then automatically closes so I cannot check my outputs.

I have tried unchecking/ checking the checkbox under tool-> debugging -> “automatically close the console when debugging stops” and restarting the software, but it still does the same thing.

Comment: Please add `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: @Markus Meyer I have tried, but the console still closes automatically.

Comment: Run it with CTRL + F5. Or add a breakpoint at the end of your main function, then run it with F5.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed this behavior when the standard input is redirected from a file in the project debug options. In this case, the console is always closed automatically, no matter what options are set in Visual Studio preferences.

The only solution I have found in this case is not to redirect standard input, or place a breakpoint at the program end.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when I redirect standard input from a file in my `args` in my `launch.vs.json` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add ReadKey to end of your main.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    aaa();
    bbb();
        
    // Wait for the user to press a key before exiting
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem sometimes with my C# projects.

I have now been able to reproduce this: My apps often have command line parameters, that are passed via the csproj/.user entry `<StartArguments>...</StartArguments>`.

The problem is that if this entry contains a line break / ends with a line break, like that:

```
...
  <StartArguments>-foo bar
  </StartArguments>

instead of:

...
  <StartArguments>-foo bar</StartArguments>
...
```

*then* the console window won't stay open.

Cleaning up this option via a text editor in the csproj / csproj.user file resolves the problem.